# Zenfone 5 a501cg soft bricked - can't mount /system /cache

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, unbricking, rom

I have a zenfone 5 which used to run on custom rom so i decided to revert it back to stock rom but when i wiped system cache and dalvik, it didn't go well and now i cannot start phone unless going into recovery. Twrp tells me those errors : 
unable to mount cache
unable to mount system

Tried flashing custom rom again but it didn't work too. Any helps please :/

ps: my phone's usb is not working as a connector to pc i.e. pc cannot recognise the phone. please keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like when you first wiped your partitions, the process was possibly interrupted and you now have corrupt partitions which are not being recognised in TWRP.

- Please go to your TWRP settings and make sure that the *use rm -rf instead of formatting* option is not checked.
- Now go *Wipe* → *Advanced Wipe* section and try wiping all those partitions again which are currently giving *unable to mount* errors. Then reboot into TWRP and try again.
- It is recommended that you use a charger during the wipe process so that a battery failure will not interrupt the process.

> Tried flashing custom rom again but it didn't work too.

Please post the error that you get while flashing or at least a part of the error that appears, so that your problem can be understood properly.

Comment: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/166818/287233) is another similar answer which might be of help. Follow the steps if you're sure that your partitions were formatted as EXT4 before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i tried going into recovery now in order to show you errors but the touch screen doesn't work now. I will try again and post screen photos showing errors later.

Comment: 1) here is the error screen i get when i try wipe [link](https://eksiup.com/p/8i2584483xo8)
2) confirming the option rm -rf is unchecked
3) tried what you said and rebooted but nothing changed
4) will post flashing rom screen soon

Comment: tried ext4 option that you've linked but it didn't help too

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I have also seen in some scenarios that this works - _Change file system_ option → format the corrupted partition(s) to some other filesystem like exFAT or FAT32 → again reformat them to ext4. Also try using the _Repair file system_ option to correct the corrupted file system.